# Overlapping CSS elements

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to make the blue element sit halfway up the green circle and behind it. How can I do that? Also, why is there a random marginal-space between the green circle and the blue element?

[image]

```
#profile-circle {
    margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;
    height: 164px; width: 164px;
    border-radius: 84px 84px 84px 84px;
}

#main-container {
    margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;
    height: 400px; width: 450px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqJ79/

Comment: You shouldn't rely on 3rd party sites in order to demonstrate your problem.  Add the important code to the question, in case jsfiddle goes down.

Comment: Thank you for using jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`position: relative`  will help you here. It allows you to use `z-index` to put the circle over the box, and also you can use `top` which will move the box relative to its current position. The problem with `position: absolute` is that it takes the element out of the flow, which is not what you need here I think.

```css
#profile-circle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

#main-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    top: -100px;
}
```

[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LqJ79/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use attributes "position: absolute;" in the second box, I updated js fiddle CSS with the following:

```
#main-container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 450px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to move the blue element up is to set a negative top margin:

```
margin-top: -82px;
```

However, with your current markup, the blue element will sit on top.

You can either put the green element below the blue one in your HTML, then use CSS to slide it up, or you can:

1. use `position: relative;` on both elements
2. set a `z-index` on the blue and green elements to determine which appears on top (give the green element a higher number so it appears on top)
3. set `top: -82px;` on the blue element to slide it up under the green one

The space between them is due to your margins:

```
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the `position: fixed;
top:10px;
left: 10px;
z-index: 1;`
and what not in the css to move them around. like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LqJ79/

Answer (score 0):

The 'magical' space between the two is due to the margin in the div user-info. I changed the CSS to the following:

```
#user-info {
height: auto;
width: 380px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

This will removed the space.